# Registro de modificaciones en mongo

Tags: mongodb

Necesito realizar un registro de histórico de modificaciones en una DB en mongo.
el back-end esta en java y front en angular
hay alguna forma de que se genere un histórico de modificaciones con alguna librería o algo parecido en mongo sin tener que crear una colección nueva de cada registro y un post con cada dato modificado

Comment: Tu pregunta se basa en opiniones. Cuando tengas una duda concreta puedes hacer la pregunta en el sitio. Te invito a repasar [ask] y a leer lo que dice el [help/on-topic] sobre el tipo de preguntas que deberías realizar en el sitio. Saludos

Comment: @MauricioContreras En SOes veo varias preguntas como estas las cuaes no son _burocráticamente_ cerradas por no ceñirse con exactitud al formato. Creo que pueden salir sugerencias interesantes que pueden servir a futuros visitantes.

Comment: @gugadev concuerdo contigo en que hay preguntas que pueden motivar comentarios o debates interesantes, e incluso visiones muy buenas de cómo resolver un problema. Pero quedan bastante fuera de lo que se considera `on-topic`. Yo apenas tengo 1 año en el sitio y aún no me paso por las preguntas más antiguas, pero siempre que puedo, sugiero la edición o voto por el cierre, ya que en mi opinión, a la larga, el contenido hace más bulto que lo que pudiese ayudar. Por eso, ante la duda (como antes comenté en el chat) aplico la regla. Saludos

Comment: me parece estupendo, pero creo que es mejor ir dando una opinión de ayuda, que todos los comentarios sean de pregunta mal realizada, la pregunta esta, modificada y creo que puede servir de ayuda a gran numero de usuarios de esta comunidad
Gracias por la opiniones

Comment: Tal vez esto te pueda orientar, en caso de que sea esto lo que buscas: [*Building with patterns: the document versioning pattern*](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/building-with-patterns-the-document-versioning-pattern). Ya dirás si es lo que buscas. Saludos